# How to remove an object and add it to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array like the following:

```json
[{
  "submittedBy": "abc@gmail.com",
  "submissionPayload": {
    "What is your name?": "hello",
    "Enter your phone number": "34567"
  }
}, {
  "submittedBy": "bcp@gm.com",
  "submissionPayload": {
    "What is your name?": "pqwer",
    "Enter your phone number": "123456789"
  }
}]
```

And I want to convert it to the following form.

```json
[{
  "submittedBy": "abc@gmail.com",
  "What is your name?": "hello",
  "Enter your phone number": "34567"
}, {
  "submittedBy": "bcp@gm.com",
  "What is your name?": "pqwer",
  "Enter your phone number": "123456789"
}]
```

I was thinking of iterating through the object and pushing the values one by one. But that seems very inefficient when I have 100s of such records.

Can you please suggest a better method?

Answer (score 2):

Map over the elements and build element by element the desired one:

```js
let input = [
    {
        "submittedBy": "abc@gmail.com",
        "submissionPayload": {
            "What is your name?": "hello",
            "Enter your phone number": "34567",
    
        }
    },
    {
        "submittedBy": "bcp@gm.com",
        "submissionPayload": {
            "What is your name?": "pqwer",
            "Enter your phone number": "123456789",
        }
   }
]
console.log(input.map( el => ({"submittedBy" : el.submittedBy, ...el.submissionPayload})))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array using `Array.map` and destructure the object. Below is the example

```js
const data = [{
  "submittedBy": "abc@gmail.com",
  "submissionPayload": {
    "What is your name?": "hello",
    "Enter your phone number": "34567"
  }
}, {
  "submittedBy": "bcp@gm.com",
  "submissionPayload": {
    "What is your name?": "pqwer",
    "Enter your phone number": "123456789"
  }
}];

const formatData = (data) => data.map(({submissionPayload, ...rest}) => ({...submissionPayload, ...rest}));

console.log(formatData(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [unpack fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Unpacking_fields_from_objects_passed_as_a_function_parameter) using object destructuring.

```js
const data = [{
  "submittedBy": "abc@gmail.com",
  "submissionPayload": {
    "What is your name?": "hello",
    "Enter your phone number": "34567"
  }
}, {
  "submittedBy": "bcp@gm.com",
  "submissionPayload": {
    "What is your name?": "pqwer",
    "Enter your phone number": "123456789"
  }
}];

const mappedData = data.map(({ submittedBy, submissionPayload }) =>
  ({ submittedBy, ...submissionPayload }));

console.log(mappedData)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing this, like by picking and constructing your object, i prefer doing with spread operator but i see there are few suggestions already with that.

```js
const data = [{
  "submittedBy": "abc@gmail.com",
  "submissionPayload": {
    "What is your name?": "hello",
    "Enter your phone number": "34567"
  }
}, {
  "submittedBy": "bcp@gm.com",
  "submissionPayload": {
    "What is your name?": "pqwer",
    "Enter your phone number": "123456789"
  }
}];


const newArr = data.map(function(item) {
  return {
    "submittedBy": item.submittedBy,
    "What is your name?": item.submissionPayload["What is your name?"],
    "Enter your phone number": item.submissionPayload["Enter your phone number"]
  };
});

console.log(newArr);
```